# How to increase maximum size of csv field in Magento, where is this located

Tags: magento, csv

I have one field when importing that can contain large data, it seems that CSV has unofficial limitation of about 65000 (likely 65535*) character. as both libreoffice calc and magento truncating the data for that particular field.  I have investigated well and I'm certain it is not because of a special character or quotes.   the data pretty straight forward, the lines are similar in format to each other.

Question: How to increase that size?  or at least where I should look to find it?

Note: I counted in libreoffice writer and it was about 65040. but probably with carriage return characters it could reach 65535

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, there is a limitation in Magento, because it sets texts fields as TEXT in MySQL database and, according to MySQL docs, this kind of field supports a maximum of 65535 chars.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/storage-requirements.html

So you could change the column type in your Magento database to use MEDIUMTEXT. I guess the correct place is in the catalog_product_entity_text table, where you should modify the 'value' field type to match your needs. But please, keep in mind this is dangerous. Make a full backup before trying. And you may even need to play with core files... not recommended!

I'm having the same issue with 8 products from a list of more than 400, and I think I'm not going to mess with Magento core and database, we can reduce the description strings for those few products.

Comment: thanks. same here  my client have decided to divide the data in several products.  my approach would have been to store the information in a more effective way that does not take that much.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, I could manage to reduce the description field length in some of the rows by doing a simple HTML markup cleaning. I mean, deleting extra spaces, duplicate "&nbsp;", empty paragraphs, etc. Don't know if you could apply the same solution.

Answer (score 2):

I change:

1) in table **catalog_category_entity_text**
type of field "value" from "text" to "longtext"

2) in file **app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Import/Entity/Abstract.php**
const DB_MAX_TEXT_LENGTH        = 65536;
to
const DB_MAX_TEXT_LENGTH        = 16777215;
and all OK

Comment: $installer->run("ALTER TABLE ".$installer->getTable('catalog_product_entity_text')." MODIFY COLUMN `value` longtext");

Answer (score 0):

The CSV could care less. Due to Microsoft Access allowing Memo fields which can contain quite a bit of data, I've exported 2-3k descriptions in CSV format to be imported into Magento quite successfully.

Your limitation is either because you are using a spreadsheet that has a cell limitation or export limitation on cells or because the field you are trying to import into has a maximum character limitation set in its table for that field.

You can determine the latter by using phpMyAdmin to see what the maximum character setting is for that field.

Comment: if you are editing the file within Microsoft Excel, your defaults fall under http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP010342495.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HP005199291

Comment: Thanks for the answer. but you might not noticed this, but I have said 65535, that's 65K > 2,3K.  as mentioned I have investigated this well enough, and I'm sure it is limitation in size in magento (my program has no limitation, because my program is in fact written by me).   I also have found this is hard coded in a constant , and also remembered that text in mysql is limited to 65535, I need to change it to mediumtext.  unfortunately magento is not flexible in this. I have to write plugin. not sure if changing it from db is enough so far.

Comment: The problem still comes down to having a program that can manipulate >65k per field and having a field width that can accept >65k. The CSV file is just a transport medium. You can try changing the field datatype and see if it will accept more than 65k (providing the import code doesn't have some hardwired limit). I would use a test server to experiment. I looked up the limits on an Access memo field and it is 65k, the character limit on Open/Libre Office cell contents is also 65k, so we'd both need something else to generate CSV with more than 65k in a field. Excel only allows 32k, fwiw.

Comment: well I generate my csv using own code in php . I only used libreoffice to check what's going on in a nice view. I think there is also a way to increase open/libreoffice handling of size.  unfortunately this is for my client , and he decided to just reduce the data . so I ll have to test this on my own server/time. I ll post results when possible.  Thanks for the answers and help.